# Error when query count product by category

Tags: php, mysql

Category table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | cat1 |
|  2 | cat2 |
|  3 | cat3 |
+----+------+
```

Product table

```
+----+-------+--------+   
| id | name  | cat_id |    
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | prod1 |      1 |    
|  2 | prod2 |      1 |    
|  3 | prod3 |      3 |    
|  4 | prod4 |      1 |    
|  5 | prod5 |      3 |
|  6 | prod6 |      1 |    
+----+-------+--------+
```

This is my query:

```
 SELECT c.id, c.name, count( p.cat_id ) num
    FROM categories c
    INNER JOIN products p ON c.id = p.cat_id
    GROUP BY p.cat_id
```

This is result:

```
+----+------+-------+    
| id | name | count |    
+----+------+-------+    
|  1 | cat1 |     4 |    
|  3 | cat3 |     2 |  
+----+------+-------+
```

Error now show count cat=2
How to fix get this result:

```
+----+------+-------+    
| id | name | count |    
+----+------+-------+    
|  1 | cat1 |     4 |    
|  2 | cat2 |     0 |    
|  3 | cat3 |     2 |  
+----+------+-------+
```

Full example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2cbb9/1

Answer (score 4):

I think, you just have to change your join into a left join.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, count( p.cat_id ) num
        FROM categories c
        LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.cat_id
        GROUP BY p.cat_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `left join`

```
 SELECT c.id, c.name, count( p.cat_id ) num
    FROM categories c
    LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.cat_id
    GROUP BY p.cat_id
```

ref : [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, count( p.cat_id ) num
        FROM categories c
        LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.cat_id
        GROUP BY p.cat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Every answer is correct that you will need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to achieve the specified result. To get the *exact* result you requested, you would need to do this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(p.cat_id) AS `count`
FROM categories AS c
LEFT JOIN products AS p ON c.id = p.cat_id
GROUP BY p.cat_id
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

The [SO question Boby referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) has a good explanation about why you can't use an `INNER JOIN` to achieve your desired result.